# Inserting radio values into database php

Tags: php

i have the complete html mixed with php codes on the link, can you guys help me identify where i went wrong and help me fix it? thanks in advance. Main problem is that I can't insert the selected/checked radio button value into the database.

http://jsfiddle.net/VeBPC/

```
$itm_chairs = $_POST['itm_chairs'];
    $itm_tables = $_POST['itm_tables'];
    $itm_speakers = $_POST['itm_speakers'];
    $itm_utensils = $_POST['itm_utensils'];
    $itm_videoke = $_POST['itm_videoke'];
    $itm_car = $_POST['itm_car'];
    $ven_pool = $_POST['ven_pool'];
    $ven_house = $_POST['ven_house'];



    if(empty($itm_chairs)) {

    } else if(empty($itm_tables)) {

    } else if(empty($itm_speakers)) {

    } else if(empty($itm_utensils)) {

    } else if(empty($itm_videoke)) {

    } 
        else{


    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_rentals(
                    res_no,itm_chairs,itm_tables,itm_speakers,itm_utensils,itm_videoke,itm_car,ven_pool,ven_house
            ) VALUES ('{$res_no}','{$itm_chairs}','{$itm_tables}','{$itm_speakers}','{$itm_utensils}','{$itm_videoke}','{$itm_car}','{$ven_pool}','{$ven_house}')";
        $result_set = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: What would happen if I passed `'; DROP TABLE tbl_rentals` to `$ven_house`?

Comment: Absolutely nothing...

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO what do you mean? why would i drop my table? D:

Comment: He's talking about SQL injection... Because you're using `mysql_*` and because you aren't sanitizing user input...

Comment: @Steven ohh ok sorry, i only know a little about php and sql.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand how to use html groups for `radio` buttons.

Where - in your `html` - you currently have groups names like:

```
name="itm_chairs[]"
```

you are supposed to have:

```
name="itm_chairs"
```

## More info

At the moment, in your `php` code you access the groups like:

```
$itm_chairs = $_POST['itm_chairs'];
```

But what you're submitting via the `html form` is interpreted as an array by `php` so `$itm_chairs` is actually an array as; opposed to a value which you think it is.

For example:

```
var_dump($itm_chairs);

/**
    Outputs something like:

    array(
       0=>(int)300
    );
*/
```

If you change the `html` group names to `itm_chair` (i.e remove `[]`) then you can do this:

```
echo $itm_chair; // Output: 300
```

Which is what you're actually after...

Comment: i removed the [] in every name on the radio button, i have it there thinking it works like the checkboxes. but still i can't seem to insert the selected/checked radio button value into the database. :(

Comment: Okay, I've looked at your code more, _in depth_ you have a query `$qry` where you reference `$res_no`. But that isn't defined anywhere? This alone will make both queries fail. Where are you getting `$res_no` from?

Comment: from another table called tbl_reservations. it is connected there. so the reservation no from tbl_reservation should be the same reservation no in the tbl_rentals.

Comment: But you use `WHERE res_no = '$res_no'` in your first query.. BEFORE you establish `$res_no` that's the same as having `WHERE res_no = ''`...

Comment: the same thing i did with the query of getting the cust_no from tbl_customer to connect with cust_no in tbl_reservation. still worked fine.